# What ingredients contribute body to a cider?

Tags: cider, recipe-formulation

I've been given a container of Suma concentrated apple juice,the concentrate used to make apple juice from concentrate, left over from a camp. I've made cider from it in the past, using just tap water and youngs super wine yeast, and it tasted very empty. What can I add to it to give it plenty of body??

Answer (score 4):

Are you really looking for body when you say the flavor was empty?
You may need a little acid blend in the final product to brighten the flavors.  Cider as a beverage is normally pretty low on body.

Next time I'd try an English Ale yeast which will attenuate slightly less, leaving you some natural apple sweetness.  At packaging you can add in a little acid blend to taste in the bottling phase.  Acid blend is available at most homebrewing shops used to help round out the flavors of wines and meads.  You can also try a little tannin extract which you may be missing as well if the original apples were skinned prior to becoming juice and concentrated.  Tannins will help with the complexity.

When I make my Ciders I tend to boil a pound of DME in a half gallon of water and add that in with 3-4 gallons of the apple juice.  Using an Enlgish Ale strain and the small amount of leftover non-fermentables from the malt extract usually helps make the cider seem sweeter and more complex. The flavor still qualifies as a dry cider, but it will seem more apple forward.

Answer (score 2):

**Malted Cider** all the way.

Basically brew a light beer wort to same gravity of juice then blend the juice and wort 50/50, ferment with a clean ale yeast like California Ale yeast.

That's the gist of it. Complete instructions are just a Google away.

Comment: I believe it's called graff.

Comment: @Mołot Graf is up to 80% wort and hopped. A Malted Cider is more along the lines of how wine coolers are considered "malt beverages". New issue if Zymurgy has a great article on malted ciders.

Answer (score 2):

You can make graff, or malted cider, as was [already answered](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/17221/12577).

Your other options are:

- Steep light crystal malt in juice to get sugars from it. Many (most?) are non fermentable. Especially malts like Carapils® by Weyermann or Cara Clair by Castlemalting are developed to provide body, but not much else.
- Experiment with different kinds of apples, they provide different body.
- Proper carbonation, not too weak, not too strong, will help as well. Find a level you like.
- Use yeast with as low attenuation as possible, they'll leave more sweetness and body behind.